# How to make a control display on top of a Windows Forms Main Menu control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'd like to place a control on top of the MainMenu control, however the designer won't let you move controls on top of the MainMenu control.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: At first why not? i try it in vs2010 all work fine, at second tell me why you want to do this?

Comment: You are correct, it does work in vs2010 just fine using the MenuStrip control. I'm working with a project that has existed since .net 1.1 which uses the MainMenu control, which doesn't support this behaviour (even with the below suggested answers).

The reason for why is that I want to implement a Quick Launch textbox similar to Visual Studio 11's Quick Launch (its at the same level as the main menu and anchored to the right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `MainMenu` control does't support this behaviour, but using a `MenuStrip` control (introduced in .net 2.0) supports this behaviour.

So I just needed to change the control to the new type to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Set Control properties as

```
  control.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
  control.SendToBack();
```